# How do you avoid the Glutton Train's Volcano Hazard attack on Nightmare/Ultimate mode without spending resources?

Tags: bloodstained-curse-of-the-moon

In Bloodstained: Curse of the Moon's Normal mode, the Glutton Train's Volcano Hazard attack can be avoided by dodging the falling fireballs as they come down. But in Nightmare and Ultimate, they leave a burning pile of debris for a while that hurts you if you touch it. But it seems like enough fireballs fall there is no place to jump to or hide. How are you supposed to avoid taking damage from this attack without spending resources (e.g., using Gebel's Immortal Metamorphosis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around, I came to what probably should have been an obvious solution: you can attack the debris, or even the fireballs as they fall, to destroy them. Then you can move to avoid the remaining fireballs without any trouble. Make sure to destroy enough that you can get up onto the coal on the left so you can avoid the follow-up Quick Bazooka blast.